# How to write SQL query for matching two conditions in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on AdventureWorks2014 Database and need to retrieve client's ID's for those clients who placed orders in BOTH years 2011 and 2014. So far I have this query:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)
HAVING COUNT(YEAR(OrderDate))=2;
```

When I try to run it though, I get an error:

> Column 'Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I tried adding `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`, but it resulted in having an empty table. I don't necessarily need to use `HAVING COUNT`, it was just one idea I came up with. Is there any way to list CustomerID's that repeat themselves in 2011 and 2014? I'm stuck, maybe I'm not seeing something simple?

**EDIT:** I really need to have both SalesOrderID and Year selected as well, not only CustomerID. That's usually where I run into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will only return matching Customer ID's if they have purchased in both 2011 and 2014

```
SELECT S.CustomerID, S.SalesOrderID, YEAR(S.OrderDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader S 
  WHERE S.CustomerId IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT S1.CustomerId FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader S1
         INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader S2 ON S1.CustomerID = S2.CustomerId
         WHERE YEAR(S1.OrderDate) = 2011 AND YEAR(S2.OrderDate) = 2014)
      AND YEAR(S.OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)
```

Comment: I did try out your query, and it seemed it worked well - I cannot figure out though how to select SalesOrderID and Year as well! I mean, I need to have a table with those three (+CustomerID, obviously) selected. Thank you for your help, do you know how could I improve it to include all three columns I need?

Comment: Seems to be working just great, thank you! :D I checked random numbers and there wasn't a mistake, not once, so I assume it's all good. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use GROUP BY CustomerID and DISTINCT keywords in the COUNT to count only one for 2014 and one for 2011 (in case if there were many orders in each year):

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(OrderDate))=2;
```

To select all orders for these customers try this:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE CustomerID IN
   (SELECT CustomerID
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
    WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)
    GROUP BY CustomerID 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(OrderDate))=2
   )
```

Or use JOIN syntax as in @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: it does work, yet I need to select not only CustomerID, but also SalesOrderID and year. That's where the problems start, it won't let me select all of these unless I include them all in group by, which results in having an empty table.

Comment: @Pauline Try the second query from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your query has conditions on the same columns, but the results will be in different rows. There are several ways to query for records of customers with purchases in both years, with or without `GROUP BY`.

Here is a straightforward way of doing it with two correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader t
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
        WHERE t.CustomerID=h.CustomerID AND YEAR(OrderDate)=2011
    )
    AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
        WHERE t.CustomerID=h.CustomerID AND YEAR(OrderDate)=2014
    )
```

Here is another way that uses `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader t
JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerID
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)
    GROUP BY CustomerID, YEAR(OrderDate)
    HAVING COUNT(*)=2
) h ON h.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
```

The "nested" query, which is used to retrieve `CustomerID`s of interest to us, closely resembles your query.

Comment: Thank you, your solution would work the best in my case, yet when I run it, the years 2013 & 2012 appear as well :( Everything else works. Is there a way to exclude all other years except for 2011 and 2014? It would have been perfect then.

Comment: @Pauline Try my query, not sure it works but it should :)

Comment: @Pauline " years 2013 & 2012 appear as well" entirely on purpose! "retrieve client's ID's for those clients who placed orders in BOTH years 2011 and 2014" does not say that you want to see only the orders placed in 2011 and 2014, only that the clients whose orders you want to see have placed *some* of their orders in both 2011 and 2014.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right, I'm sorry. I was confused at first but now I see my mistake. I guess I should've specified that I wanted the years shown up in the table to be only 2011 and 2014. I mean, your result shows the right ID's, I just needed to skip the results with the years inbetween. Sorry for not clarifying that, and thank you for your help! I really like how in your solution it's all more orderly.

Comment: @Pauline You can always filter the results by adding a `WHERE` clause at the bottom, or in case of the first query by adding an `AND YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)` at the end.

Comment: You need to use distinct count in your second query otherwise your query won't work and you could get scenarios where the person has two sales in 2011 or 2014

Comment: @Josh You are right, I needed to do a distinct, or add `YEAR(OrderDate)` to the `GROUP BY` list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way to do what you want is to use window functions:

```
SELECT soh.CustomerID, soh.SalesOrderID, YEAR(soh.OrderDate) AS [Year]
FROM (SELECT soh.*,
             MIN(YEAR(OrderDate)) OVER () as miny,
             MAX(YEAR(OrderDate)) OVER () as maxy
      FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
      WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011, 2014)
     ) soh
WHERE miny < maxy;
```